# Is that possible to query millions of row back with ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

I know ClickHouse may be not the proper database to get millions of row (only a few columns) back with SQL like below:

```
select col1, col2, .., date from table where col0='a1' and date >= 'start_date' and date 'end_date'
```

But currently I face a situation on that. Could someone tell me the performance for that?

```
1. Maximize rows queried from one "select" SQL 
2. Any optimization for fast response
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CH able to return millions rows per sec.

Test with 100mil rows / 3GB:

```
CREATE TABLE XX
ENGINE = MergeTree
ORDER BY A AS
SELECT
    number AS A,
    toDate(number % 103) AS B,
    toString(number) AS C,
    number % 1003 AS D
FROM numbers(100000000)

time curl -o t 'http://localhost:8123/?query=select%20A,%20B,%20C,%20D%20from%20XX'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 3115M    0 3115M    0     0   413M      0 --:--:--  0:00:07 --:--:--  404M

real    0m7.840s


time clickhouse-client -q 'select A,B,C,D from XX' > /dev/null
real    0m6.451s
```

1 mil rows / 30MB

```
time curl -o /dev/null 'http://localhost:8123/?query=select%20A,%20B,%20C,%20D%20from%20XX%20prewhere%20B=toDate(1)'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 30.2M    0 30.2M    0     0  93.0M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 92.7M

real    0m0.329s

time clickhouse-client -q 'select A,B,C,D from XX prewhere B=toDate(1)' > /dev/null

real    0m0.344s
```